# django.utils.timezone returning naive date?

Tags: django, timezone

using django 1.4 I have a model with a datetimefield. I imported django.utils.timezone to use as the default value.

```
from django.utils import timezone
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

however I still receive the warning about DateTimeField received naive date. 
i have set USE_TZ to true so it should be returning aware datetimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

djangos putting in a default date value that isn't tz aware because the field isnt nullable by default. setting null to true means it will just set the date to to NULL instead so the warning isnt raised:

```
 date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
```

Comment: I may be ignorant, but I don't understand what null has to do with timezone.now() being naive.  If Null = True than .now() will return an aware object?

Comment: the default value django was putting in was not timezone aware

Comment: @mobiletim I am still a bit confused by this, why would setting `null = True` make the error go away?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I kept receiving the issue when I ran tests. This is because of a past migration that incorrectly used datetime instead of timezone. I reverted back to the migration before the one causing the warning, deleted it, ran makemigrations again. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

> `now()`
>
> Returns an aware or naive datetime that represents the current
>   point in time when `USE_TZ` is `True` or `False` respectively.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now

Comment: i have set USE_TZ to true so it should be returning aware datetimes

Answer (score -1):

I know this is side-stepping the issue but have you tried `auto_now_add=True` on your field instead? No need to use `default` for what you want.

On the other hand your version **should** work as well if you have indeed `USE_TZ=True`.

I'd say it does work, and you get the `RunTimeWarning` from somewhere where you set the `date` field directly instead and not from the default. Try to narrow down when is the warning triggered more exactly.

Comment: auto_now_add is bad style for timezone-aware Django applications

Comment: @fangsterr May I ask why do you think that? It would be more useful if you'd also explain your reasoning.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195020/why-django-lint-tells-me-the-auto-now-add-is-deprecated