# Why does django-lint tell me the `auto_now_add` is deprecated?

Tags: python, django, datetime, last-modified, pylint

Hi fellow Djangonauts:

I checked my project with [django-lint](https://chris-lamb.co.uk/projects/django-lint/), and it yields:

```
W:211,16:MyModel: timestamp: Uses superceded auto_now or auto_now_add
```

The [commit message](https://github.com/lamby/django-lint/commit/131d6cdaa83e7e196246387471c321991ef59696):

```
auto_now/auto_now_add not technically deprecated, but they still suck.
```

Why do they say auto_now/auto_now_add "suck"? I had no problem implementing the created/last-updated pattern with these two field parameters.

Is there a better approach for this pattern? Custom Field classes? And why (if this approach is better) it hasn't been integrated into Django?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct fix is to pass a callable as the field's `default` that returns the appropriate datetime, e.g. `datetime.datetime.now`.

Comment: One could say that `auto_now_add=True` is a shortcut for `default=datetime.now(), editable=False, blank=True`. But how to implement `auto_now=True`?

Comment: Override the `save()` method, and set it there.

Comment: Also, `default=datetime.now`.

Comment: Oops... the parenthesis slipped away :) Regarding the `save` method, I think it's too much boilerplate to manually include for such a common pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`auto_now` and `auto_now_add` are considered harmful, because you have absolutely no way to change the value via django (say for example, in the admin interface).

This is an inconsitency with other flags, and django people generally don't like that sort of magic.

Comment: A field that reflects the creation time (or last modification time) doesn't make much sense to me to be editable in the admin.

Comment: sometimes you want to fake things. consider backups and their restore.

Comment: I've just been convinced that I don't ever want to use DjangoLint. If there's an actual flaw in auto_add and auto_add_new, they should be fixed. But that's not the case here.

Considering something that you're not required to use to be bad because it doesn't meet your personal requirements is narrow and short-sighted. Don't use it and don't think that you understand everybody else's requirements. To many people, the fact that the value cannot be changed easily is a feature, not a bug.

Things that some people happen to not like don't belong in a Lint program.

Comment: @roy-leban It's not just one guy's personal requirements, it's [long](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/TNYxwiXLTlI) been thought to be an antipattern: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22995

Comment: @TomCarrick Just saw this old comment. A widely-held opinion is still an opinion. The pages you linked to discuss other ways to accomplish the same thing and whether those ways should supplant these ways. This doesn't make it an antipattern at all. It makes it a pattern people use and like and are discussing the best way to do it. Given that auto_now and auto_now_add are probably used in hundreds of thousands of places, deprecating them because some people don't like them isn't a good idea. The comment someone made that removing them would help people learn important APIs is just foolish.