# Django: datetime.now() time inconsistency in model object save

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

[image]

The above is one of my tables in admin interface in the descending order of `id`(recent record is at top). And here is the way I used to create the model objects and save.

```
notification = Notification(from_user=from_user, to_user=to_user,
                            created_date=datetime.now())
notification.save()
```

All the inserts to this table `Notification` are done only in the various `post_save` signal handlers. Will it cause any inconsistencies like these?

Using `TIME_ZONE = 'GMT'` in django 1.3.2. I could try with `auto_now_add=True` option in the model but before that just want to know why this is happening.

Comment: `datetime.now()` returns local time, so the only way I can see that this could occur is if different requests have a different local time zone.  Is that possible in your app at all?  Try `datetime.utcnow()`.  It's generally good practice to store dates in UTC anyway.

Comment: +1 for utc mentioning. But I believe that the `datetime.now()` returns local time(machine time or the one given in `TIME_ZONE`) rather than the request time zone. So there should be an another way.

Comment: What platform are you on?  Windows per chance?

Comment: nope. In Ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 5):

`auto_now_add` is not a good approach. Avoid to use it. The best way is to use set default value:

```
from django.utils import timezone

date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

`django.utils.timezone` will store the datetime according to your timezone settings.

Notice the missing `()` after `timezone.now` that is because we are passing a callable to the model and it will be called each time a new instance is saved. With the parentheses, it's only being called once when `models.py` loads. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225890/django-default-timezone-now-saves-records-using-old-time) clarifies this issue in more details.

Comment: Why is `auto_now_add` not a good approach and should it be avoided?

Comment: Yes, I also would like to know.

Comment: There is a lot of discussion in past about auto_now and auto_now_add. I will give some reference links here see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195020/why-django-lint-tells-me-the-auto-now-add-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

You should not initialize the datetime.now() while defining the model. This causes some kind of "caching" the datetime.now.

Instead of:

```
Notification(from_user=from_user, to_user=to_user,
                            created_date=datetime.now())
```

You should use:

```
Notification(from_user=from_user, to_user=to_user,
                            created_date=datetime.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's due to the way Pythons runtime environment processes, hopefully someone can re-iterate on that.
auto_add_now=True should be the solution as you've suggested.

Comment: Could you please post anything in detail regarding the `runtime environment process`?